# What do infinitives mean in news headlines?

Tags: infinitives, headline-english

I can't wrap my head around some English news titles with infinitives (I have tried to Google this, hopelessly).

Some examples:

> - **Russia's Head Athletics Coach *to Step Down* After Doping Revelations**[¹](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2015/01/23/russias-head-athletics-coach-to-step-down-after-doping-revelations-a43188)
> - **Russia *to Create* Government Job to Fight Doping in Sport**[²](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2015/01/22/russia-to-create-government-job-to-fight-doping-in-sport-a43129)
> - **Russian Olympic Champion Kaniskina *to Quit* Executive Role Over Doping Scandal**[³](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2015/01/22/russian-olympic-champion-kaniskina-to-quit-executive-role-over-doping-scandal-a43117)

What is this use of infinitives called, and what does it mean?

Comment: Try adding an "is going to" in front of the infinitive:  "Russia's Head Athletics Coach **is going to step down** After Doping Revelations"   Headlines try to compress as much meaning into as few words as possible so they are nearly always going to be missing words that would be present in everyday conversation.

Comment: Probly _is expected to `Infinitive`, it was announced_. This is what's used when an official announcement is, um, announced, and there is comment, blowback, or explanation. It's from the construction _He is to leave tomorrow_, which means 'His departure is scheduled  for tomorrow, but he's nevertheless still here'.

Comment: Answered at the 'The form of future implication: to be [. . .]' thread. (1) and (3) above are examples of be-deletion; the terse style used in headlines has been dubbed _headlinese_. Be-deletion also occurs in (2) (_Russia **is** to Create ..._). The second usage is short (but very common) for 'aimed at [fighting]'; elsewhere it could be short for 'in order to'.

Comment: There's also the gerund used on NBC News on TV: "President Biden announcing today that he is appointing John X. Doe to his cabinet." In standard English one could say "President Biden announced today that he is appointing John X. Doe to his cabinet." NBC News, or maybe TV news in general, has invented a new journalese verb tense.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That usage is not only on NBC and it drives me right round the bloody bend. There is no excuse for their not using a "normal", usually tensed verb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the days of print media headlines had to be short to fit over the column or columns of text in the article.  In order to make them shorter editors often leave out words that most native speakers could intuit from context.  So the full headlines for your example would be as follows:

Russia's Head Athletics Coach is About to Step Down After Doping Revelations.

Russia is going to Create a Government Job to Fight Doping in Sport.

Russian Olympic Champion Kaniskina is About to Quit his Executive Role Over the Doping Scandal

There are other potentially correct ways to write the full version but they would have similar meaning.

Comment: So it usually means just intentions, right? Are there any cases where we should add "have to" or "must"? Or it simply depends on the context of the news?

Comment: It always means what *will* happen, or what is predicted to happen, in the future.

Comment: In other words, it's a way of using an untensed infinitive clause to refer to a future event. Replacing *to* with either modal *will* or the tensed periphrastic version *is going to* does not change the meaning at all. So this is something of an elliptical future.

Comment: "is going to" or "is about to" could also be written "will", but "to" is shorter